# Will changing the remote url to be ssh cause issues for team members not using ssh?

Tags: github, ssh

I'm trying to get set up with SSH. One of the steps mentioned converting any existing remotes from https to ssh and the instructions to actually do it seem clear enough https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url

I'm curious though will other team members still be able to connect via https to that remote repository? Are there any other unintended consequences that could occur?

Answer (score 0):

Changing a local remote repository URL doesn't affect anyone but you.

In the case of GitHub, it's acceptable and common for one team member (e.g. a full-time employee) to have an SSH remote, and another to have an HTTPS remote. GitHub provides both.

You can use both, too. You'll just have a different experience when you push to one remote versus the other:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:hashrocket/tilex.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:hashrocket/tilex.git (push)
origin-https    https://github.com/hashrocket/tilex.git (fetch)
origin-https    https://github.com/hashrocket/tilex.git (push)
```